# Getting "can't convert string to float" error using pandas and python?

Tags: python, pandas

How to convert string to float? Here is my code, I tried using dtype and
astype method:

```
for f in files:
    data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, f), sep=";", dtype={"Unnamed: 5":float})
    data=data.drop(data.index[:4])
    df = df.append(data)
for x in df:
    print(x)
    if x == "Unnamed: 0":
        feeName = df["Unnamed: 0"]
        generalLedger = df["Unnamed: 3"]
        amount = df["Unnamed: 5"].astype(np.float64)
        print(feeName, generalLedger, amount)
      
index = 0

sumManagementFee = 0

for x in feeName:
    if x == "Management Fee":
        rows = float(amount.iloc[index])
        sumManagementFee += rows
```

The error is:

> File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 756, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
> File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 771, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
> File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 850, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
> File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 982, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data
> File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1056, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens
> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Amount'

Comment: What's the _full_ error message?

Comment: data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 756, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 771, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 850, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 982, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1056, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Amount'

Comment: Looks like the `Unnamed: 5` column contains the literal string `"Amount"` which can't be parsed as float, yet `{"Unnamed: 5":float}` in your code says that _all_ values of that columns are floats.

Comment: How can I then use data as floats, except for the Amount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, your error shows that there is an `'Amount'` string in the column `"Unnamed: 5"` that you're trying to convert.

You can remove it manually, or you can try using `pd.to_numeric`:

```
amount = pd.to_numeric(df["Unnamed: 5"], errors='coerce')
```

Instead of

```
amount = df["Unnamed: 5"].astype(np.float64)
```

Specifying argument `errors='coerce'` will replace all invalid values with NaN

Comment: Actually it didn't. Now amount is full of nan values

Comment: Check your amount column. It is full of 'nan' values because the values stored there might be invalid (as the error says, e.g you're having 'Amount' value in that column, which is string)

Comment: Amount is in dataframe but not in amount. amount has a strings as '2014.12'